# Php SQL doesn't work. but in phpmyadmin SQL tab it works in GoDaddy servers

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using goDaddy server.
This page doesn't work but when I copy paste SQL output to phpmyadmin SQL tab, it works. Some pages have same status. Some pages which has "insert into" query, it works. This page works on my computer seamlessly

```
include('database.php');

$resimurl="some url";

$sql = "INSERT INTO gruplar (grupadı,resim,uyesayı,gelenkutusayı) SELECT '" . $adı ."','" . $resimurl ."',1,0 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idi FROM gruplar WHERE grupadı='". $adı. "')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
die($sql);
```

databese.php

```
$servername = "bla bla";
$username = "bla";
$password = "bla";
$dbname = "db name";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("HATA"); //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

I want to remind that some pages which use this database.php works seamlessly.

Thanks for your help.

I solved problem with chancing table column name "ı" to "i". ex(grupadı => grupadi )
It was not about undefined variable.
I think it is about comminication of databese
and php works with $adı variable. 
Thanks for help

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: I see an undefined variable. Turn on error reporting.

Comment: `$adı` is that a 1 or a l or what charterset?

Comment: INSERT INTO gruplar (grupadı,resim,uyesayı,gelenkutusayı) SELECT 'string','string',1,0 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idi FROM gruplar WHERE grupadı='string')                                               You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�,resim,uyesayı,gelenkutusayı) SELECT 'sdsadassdasd','http://bla bla.c' at line 1                                                            maybe it is about � this character ?

Comment: $adı is a string  @johnConde  "bla abdasd bla"

Comment: Per http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php `$adı` is an invalid variable name. Your column name `grupadı` would also fall into the same category but for mysql column names. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: that was my point, you seem to be using a "non standard" character-set there for php variables